# CMake: Fortran modules and compilation order

Tags: cmake, fortran

I have a big Fortran program which contains many directories. Each directory is compiled separately in a pseudo-library, but there is still an interdependency mess, so at the end all pseudo-libraries are combined in a single usable library. I'd like to use Fortran modules, but it's very fragile, since I cannot rely on automatic dependency checking, and compilation may fail depending on the order.

For instance, consider the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project (test Fortran)
add_library (lib1 dir1/lib1.f90)
add_library (lib2 dir2/lib2.f90 dir2/mod.f90)
add_executable (exe dir3/exe.f90)
target_link_libraries (exe lib1 lib2)
```

With the sources:

`dir1/lib1.f90`:

```
subroutine bar
use foo, only: foofoo
implicit none
write(6,*) foofoo
end subroutine bar
```

`dir2/lib2.f90`:

```
subroutine bar2
use foo, only: foofoo
implicit none
write(6,*) foofoo,' again'
end subroutine bar2
```

`dir2/mod.f90`:

```
module foo
implicit none
integer :: foofoo=3
end module foo
```

`dir3/exe.f90`:

```
program meh
implicit none
call bar()
call bar2()
end program meh
```

Compiling from scratch fails:

```
$ make
[ 25%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/dir1/lib1.f90.o
/home/user/cmake/dir1/lib1.f90:2.4:

use foo, only: foofoo
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'foo.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/dir1/lib1.f90.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

but doing it in the right order works:

```
$ make lib2
Scanning dependencies of target lib2
[ 50%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/dir2/mod.f90.o
[100%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/dir2/lib2.f90.o
Linking Fortran static library liblib2.a
[100%] Built target lib2
$ make
[ 25%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/dir1/lib1.f90.o
Linking Fortran static library liblib1.a
[ 25%] Built target lib1
[ 75%] Built target lib2
Scanning dependencies of target exe
[100%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/exe.dir/dir3/exe.f90.o
Linking Fortran executable exe
[100%] Built target exe
```

Is there any way CMake can figure out the dependency and compile `lib2` (or at least `mod.f90`) before `lib1`?

ETA: A robust solution should work regardless of the order in which `lib1` and `lib2` are defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and, once the program has been compiled, after running `rm foo.mod ; touch ../dir1/lib1.f90`.

Comment: What is your version of cmake? `cmake --version`

Comment: For info, "cmake version 3.13.4" resolves the dependency properly.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I've tried 2.8.12.2 and 3.8.1.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to update? If you don't have an up-to-date package on your system's package manager installing from source is quite painless :-) https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: @PierredeBuyl It should be feasible, since that's the way I got 3.8.1. In the meantime, I tried in another machine where I have 3.13.2, and got the same error. Did something relevant change from 3.13.2 to 3.13.4? Did you somehow compile `mod.f90` first? Or is this a random/system dependent behaviour?

Comment: I wrote all the files from a copy-paste of your question. Then `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..` and `make`.

Comment: If you have already attempted compilation, consider clear all of cmake's cache with `rm -r CMake*` *in the build directory*. Before using `rm`, make sure that you are in the proper directory and that `CMake*` is only the cached files.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I compiled 3.14.5 and indeed it worked, but not after `rm foo.mod ; touch ../dir1/lib1.f90`. Actually, just changing the order of `lib1` and `lib2` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file made it fail with 3.14.5 and work with 2.8.12.2.

Comment: This is weird, it should not need that specific order of operation. On my computer, `lib1.f90` is created earlier than `lib2.f90` and it still works. Did you do the `rm -r CMake*` thing? Do you build "in source tree" or "out of source tree"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195139/discussion-between-jellby-and-pierre-de-buyl).

Answer (score 4):

The [upcoming ninja build system version (1.10.0)](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/pull/1521) has support for dynamic dependencies, which will resolve modules compilation order correctly.

To use it with CMake, you have to specify the `Ninja` generator:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja # generate project
ninja # build the project
```

Answer (score 4):

Here problem is that `lib1` target required object file for `mod.f90`. But there is no rule mention in `CMakeLists.txt` to create `mod.f90.o` while creating `liblib1.a`. For `lib2` target `mod.f90.o` is created.

There can be two possible solution as below.

**Solution-1**

Add `mod.f90` to both library.

```
project (test Fortran)
add_library (lib1 dir1/lib1.f90 dir2/mod.f90)
add_library (lib2 dir2/lib2.f90 dir2/mod.f90)
add_executable (exe dir3/exe.f90)
target_link_libraries (exe lib1 lib2)
```

**Solution-2**

Link library with `mod.f90.o` to other one.

```
project (test Fortran)
add_library (lib1 dir1/lib1.f90)
add_library (lib2 dir2/lib2.f90 dir2/mod.f90)
add_dependencies(lib1 lib2)
add_executable (exe dir3/exe.f90)
target_link_libraries (exe lib1 lib2)
```

Comment: Exactly, I need a way for CMake to detect that `lib1` requires `foo.mod`, and therefore depends on `mod.f90`. Any solution where I need to manually specify this dependency (either at file level or at library level) is only leading to a maintenance hell. It works for this simple example, but won't be worth it for a large project with lots of possibly interconnected directories/libraries.